# ViewConfiguration.getScaledTouchSlop returns pixels or DP (density independant pixels)?

Tags: android

In this android doc https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html it says that
getScaledTouchSlop returns a value in pixel. But the sample line put the value in a constant named DP.

```
private static final int GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP = ViewConfiguration.get(myContext).getScaledTouchSlop();
```

This is confusing. The doc of ViewConfiguration itself does not explain more what getScaled means.

Should i convert DP to px before using the value, to compare it with MotionEvent.getY() which return pixels ?

Comment: Downvoting without living a comment should be prohibited.

Comment: could you get an answer on this? I believe the answer is DP, but I also believe the documentation is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the value in pixels, but scaled to the density of the device. i.e. it returns the DP value converted to pixel value.

So you don't have to convert it to pixel again.

For example, say, if it returns value 10 for mdpi device. Then it will return 40 for xxxhdpi (4 times of mdpi) device.

I guess, they used DP in the constant field name, since it returns the pixel value scaled to the density of the device. So we can use the method without concerning the density of the devices, which ultimately means density-independent pixels.

Comment: So pixel or DP ? You answer is confusing too. MotionEvent.getY() returns pixels not DP.

Comment: Android doc: "Distance in pixels a touch can wander before we think the user is scrolling"